# how can we add "\n" to Stringified JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add '\n' on each line break. Can it be achieved using reg expression

```
 {
  "name": " ",
  "type": "column",
  "axis": "vertical",
  "content_type": "stack_view",
  "contents": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "type": "row",
      "axis": "horizontal",
      "content_type": "field",
      "contents": [],
      "isParentBlock": false,
      "weight": 100
    }
  ],
  "isParentBlock": true,
  "weight": 100
}
```

PS- I want to achieve something like below.

{\r\n  \"name\": \"FormStack\",\r\n  \"type\": \"row\",\r\n  \"axis\": \"horizontal\",\r\n  \"content_type\": \"stack_view\",\r\n  \"contents\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \" \",\r\n      \"type\": \"column\",\r\n      \"axis\": \"vertical\",\r\n      \"content_type\": \"stack_view\",\r\n      \"contents\": [\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"\",\r\n          \"type\": \"row\",\r\n          \"axis\": \"horizontal\",\r\n          \"content_type\": \"field\",\r\n          \"contents\": [\r\n            [\r\n              {\r\n                \"title\": \"Signature\",\r\n                \"value\": \"\",\r\n                \"optional\": \"\",\r\n                \"type\": \"signature_stack\",\r\n                \"identifier\": \"\",\r\n                \"values\": [],\r\n                \"properties\": {\r\n                  \"mandatory\": \"\",\r\n                  \"rule\": \"\"\r\n                },\r\n                \"buttons\": [],\r\n                \"weight\": 50,\r\n                \"wrap\": false,\r\n                \"$$hashKey\": \"object:137\"\r\n              }\r\n            ],\r\n            [\r\n              {\r\n                \"title\": \"Enter Title\",\r\n                \"value\": \"\",\r\n                \"optional\": \"\",\r\n                \"type\": \"text_view\",\r\n                \"identifier\": \"\",\r\n                \"values\": [],\r\n                \"properties\": {\r\n                  \"mandatory\": \"\",\r\n                  \"rule\": \"\"\r\n                },\r\n                \"buttons\": [],\r\n                \"weight\": 50,\r\n                \"wrap\": false,\r\n                \"$$hashKey\": \"object:151\"\r\n              }\r\n            ]\r\n          ],\r\n          \"isParentBlock\": false,\r\n          \"weight\": 50\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n          \"name\": \"\",\r\n          \"type\": \"row\",\r\n          \"axis\": \"horizontal\",\r\n          \"content_type\": \"field\",\r\n          \"contents\": [],\r\n          \"isParentBlock\": false,\r\n          \"weight\": 50\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      \"isParentBlock\": true,\r\n      \"weight\": 100\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"isParentBlock\": true,\r\n  \"weight\": 100\r\n}

Comment: `/n` or `\n` ...?

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(myData, null, 2)```?

Comment: You mean `'\n'` (newline character) ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myData, null, "\n")`

Comment: sorry, my bad its '\n' . Edited.